# Symfony2 - How to fetch/join only related entities with a certain condition (one-to-many relation)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a onetomany relationship between event and participant entities.
In my controller i can do the following:

```
$participants = $event->getParticipant();
```

But now i only want the Participants where the property `visible` has the value 1.

how can i get those collection? because participant is an arraycollection of all participants with `participant.event_id = event.id` in the event entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a method in your `EventRepository` that joins only the visible participants with the event:

```
// YourBundle/Entity/EventRepository.php

public function getEventFilterVisibleParticipants($event_id)
{
    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('event')
        ->where('event.id = :event_id')
        ->leftJoin('event.participants', 'participant', 'WITH', 'participant.visible = :visibility')
        ->setParameter('event_id', $event_id)
        ->setParameter('visibility', 1)
        ->orderBy('event.startDate', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

... Now in your controller do something like this:

```
$event = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('YourBundle:Event')
    ->getEventFilterVisibleParticipants($id)
;

$participants = $event->getParticipants(); // returns the filtered collection
```

Comment: it says Undefined method 'getEventWithVisibleParticipants'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Comment: I had changed the method name from `getEventWithVisibleParticipants` to `getEventFilterVisibleParticipants` in my answer after posting. make sure you're getting the correct repository from doctrine and check the method names are matching :)

Comment: but i have found an easier solution - i just filter it in the twig-template by its visibility while looping through the objects ;)

Comment: This might be "easier" but it **limits** the possiblity to do something with only the visible participants to your template ... further it's **BAD** in terms of performance because you're fetching entities from the database that you actually don't need. That's the reason you should use the repository method - it's exactly the purpose of the repository to provide these methods.